# maven-release-plugin changes java version

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

I have a weird problem with the maven-release-plugin, because it somehow uses another java version as the one which is used for the execution of maven. My initial situation is a bit strange. So we are using a CI/CD server where each module has its own jdk configuration. The CI/CD server has its `JAVA_HOME` environment variable set to Java 8, but we have multiple jdks installed, so that for example Java 11 can be used for the build process of a specific project. I checked the log output of the build process and noticed that this command is used for the maven execution and for switching between different jdks:

```
"/path/to/java" "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/path/to/my-project" "-Dmaven.home=/path/to/maven" "-Dclassworlds.conf=/path/to/maven/bin/m2.conf" "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" -classpath "/path/to/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;/path/to/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds.license" org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher clean package
```

So you can just swap `/path/to/java` and maven uses this jdk for the build process. If you check for example the file `mvn.cmd`, you will notice that this is the exact command maven uses internally to trigger the build process.

OK, now let me explain my problem. I am using a custom maven plugin where I inserted this command in the code:

```
getLog().info("java version: " + System.getProperty("java.runtime.version"));
```

Now, when I execute the above command with `clean package` at the end and with `/path/to/java` pointing to jdk11, the log output is: `java version: 11.0.5+10-LTS`. If I use `release:prepare` instead of `clean package` at the end (still with jdk11), the output is `java version: 1.8.0_231-b11`. So somehow the maven-release-plugin does not use the jdk which is used for the execution of maven, but uses `JAVA_HOME` instead. This only happens when using the release plugin. With the regular maven goals (clean, package, install, deploy) jdk11 is used, so in this case the one which is located at `/path/to/java`. Does anyone know why? And maybe someone has a solution how I can make the release plugin not to change the jdk (without changing JAVA_HOME).

Comment: Did you check https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#javaHome ? That is the way the control the Java version, which should be the same by default.

Comment: Which CI/CD server do you use? How is the setup done for each job?

Answer (score 0):

I am already passing the path to my jdk via `-DjavaHome`, but this does not do anything. I debugged the maven-release-plugin and noticed that in InvokerMavenExecutor the setting for javaHome is not passed to the executor. So I guess this is a bug in that plugin. I will create a bug ticket for this.

Comment: Have you tried to switch to another [mavenExecutorId](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#mavenExecutorId)? `forked-path` should honour `javaHome`

Comment: Unfortunately forked-path also ignores javaHome. There even is a pull request for solving that bug, but it was never merged. https://github.com/apache/maven-release/pull/5